# C# and Service Reference - "override" serialization in partial class

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to communicate with **Oracle's Utilities App Framework SOAP service**, for which I'm using the auto-generated service reference. Unfortunately, the server formats some response `DateTime` fields in such a way that it causes a deserialization error.

Since I don't want to modify the auto-generated code (e.g. using `XmlIgnore` gets the job done), is there any other way to somehow modify serialization behaviour without inheriting the base class and overriding properties? I'm hoping to be able to re-format the field on deserialization. Is it even possible to do?